# Unexpected response code 500 during POST request to RESTful CART API

Tags: java, post, cart

I am currently using a RESTful API for Woocommerce to add items into cart. It's supposed to accept "product_id" and "quantity" as the parameters based on the documentation for the API in which I used the following code to do so:

```
JSONObject addcart = new JSONObject();

    try {
        addcart.put("product_id", 28);
        addcart.put("quantity", 1);
        Log.e("params", addcart.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, domain+api,addcart,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };


    Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(request);

}
```

However I received this error message when executing the POST request:

```
E/params: {"product_id":28,"quantity":1} 
E/Volley: [365] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for http://domain+api
```

The product is not added into the cart and through a GET request the response is  "Cart is empty!". What am I doing wrong? I am pretty sure the the API works but I can't figure out why my POST request isn't going through and constantly getting error 500. Can anyone give me some advice?

(If anyone wants to know the doc: https://seb86.github.io/WooCommerce-Cart-REST-API-Docs/?shell#add-to-cart)

Comment: Log the rest of the error response, i.e. the payload/body. It may explain why it failed.

Comment: There is probably some exception being thrown

Comment: Do you mean something like "Log.e("Error", error.toString());" under onErrorResponse? If so the message is "E/Error: com.android.volley.ServerError". Or am I supposed to log something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the problem after using the code below:

```
 StringRequest addrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://domainname/test/wp-json/wc/v2/cart/add?product_id=28&quantity=14" ,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Response", response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("Error", error.toString());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            boolean dbempty = helper.checklogin();
            if (!dbempty) {
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + helper.getToken());
            }
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }
    };
    Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(addrequest);
```

I received the following String request response and the item is indeed added on my localhost website:

```
E/Response: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  is_numeric() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\rest-api\class-wp-rest-request.php</b> on line <b>858</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  is_numeric() expects exactly 1 parameter, 3 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-includes\rest-api\class-wp-rest-request.php</b> on line <b>858</b><br />
{"key":"33e75ff09dd601bbe69f351039152189","product_id":28,"variation_id":0,"variation":[],"quantity":14,"line_tax_data":{"subtotal":[],"total":[]},"line_subtotal":979.86,"line_subtotal_tax":0,"line_total":979.86,"line_tax":0,"data":{}}
```

I had tried other POST method String request where I received the exact same warning message and the POST request did not went through but it worked when I did it this way eventhough I still receive the error message. But hope this helps others using the same API with the same problem.

NOTE: The new header I added which consists of Authorization key and Bearer Token value is to give each user a unique CART of their own so that they do not share the same cart. This is not needed to solve the problem.